# MySql. Fulltext search "some text ... and more" in "some text .../.../.../ and more"

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table with rows like:

- What variety/species/subspecies/type/subtype/class/subclass is
- What kind of object is
- What is the common name/name for/for
- ...
  Here a list of words through a slash means that at this place can be any(only one) of these words. Situations are also possible when this word consists of two, i.e. includes a space, as described in thrid example.

I want to find a row by value like: "what species is", "what type is",  "What is the common name". Is it possible to do this with fulltext search or anothery way, it does't matter. I came up with a solution with several tables, but it is too cumbersome.

**More about this**

The table, is described above is it:

```
    CREATE TABLE `qa_question` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `question_mask` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,  
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
```

It contains a list of text questions to the database of my site. These questions are entered into it manually by the administrator. These questions are then entered by the user and the system should show him certain data. It doesn’t matter what kind of data, it is important to match the input from the user with the database.

It's working on web site under laravel famework.
Example:
"What variety/species/subspecies/type/subtype/class/subclass is?" question from the database is equal to this:

- What variety is
- What species is
- What subspecies is
- and so on...

P.S.:While I was writing this, the thought came that I could pack all this into a graph and do a search on it, which is already easier.

Comment: "MsSql" implies "Microsoft SQL Server" which is not the same as "MySQL". Which do you want?

Comment: @tadman MySql, sorry misprint...

Comment: Good clarification. You're going to need to add more specifics here. This is thin on sample data. It's also lacking a schema we can build on to produce examples. Remember MySQL should not be the only tool in your toolbox. Consider tools like [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co) as well.

Comment: @tadman Thank you. While I was looking about elastic, another thought occurred to me. I'm going to try. updated description